# Allow only English letters without spaces or number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to make my input text just accept English letter without spaces or number or can copy and paste in it!

I have tried this code and it works but when I copy and paste anything outside input it accept the value:

```
const regex = /[A-Za-z]/;

function validate(e) {
    const chars = e.target.value.split('');
    const char = chars.pop();
    if (!regex.test(char)) {
        e.target.value = chars.join('');
    }
}

document.querySelector('#inputTextBox').addEventListener('input', validate);
```

How can I make it not allow to copy and paste value out of input?

feel free to use `Jquery` or pure `JS`

Comment: By adding `change` to the listener?

Comment: well your code is only looking at the last letter. It would also fail if the user moved the cursor to a different spot in the textbox and typed.

Comment: @epascarello ohh that's right!! any solve pls?

Comment: `const regex = /^[a-z]+$/i`

Comment: This was closed as a dupe of a question and answer both specifically dealing with the React library.  Since this question has nothing to do with React it should be reopened unless there is a more appropriate dupe out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `oninput` event with `replace` to restrict input like this:

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) event.

So in order to prevent user from pasting anything which is not allowed

`document.querySelector('#inputTextBox').addEventListener('paste', validate);`

You may reset the value of input after validating.

Comment: input handles paste. Issue was pointed out in comments, not sure what copy has to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is not really necessary, you can use `match`

```js
function validate(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.match(/[A-Za-z]/g).join('');
}

document.querySelector('#inputTextBox').addEventListener('input', validate);
```

```html
<input id="inputTextBox"/>
```

Comment: Cool but when I'm trying  to write with another language is accept and I said just english

Comment: Paste `ååååååååååååå` into the textbox with no value, you get error

Comment: all the solution will allow this, you should check against an english dictionary. Also, `å` is not in `A-Za-z` regex

Comment: you are also reinventing replace()